# Golang Websocket Custom JSON Messages

Tags: go, gorilla

I'm trying to send/receive custom JSON messages. There are 3 cases in which the JSON struct changes, therefore I have 3 different structs. I have to access the room string which is sent as RawMessage. My question is what type should the channel Broadcast be?

```
type Message struct {
    Type int64 `json:"type"`
    Msg  json.RawMessage
}
```

`Broadcast chan interface{}  // ??? RawMessage or maybe interface`

```
          case m := <-r.Broadcast:
            // What type should chan Broadcast be?
            // If m is of type json.RawMessage should I deal with unmarshalling here?
            connections := r.Clients[m.Room] // 
            for c := range connections {
                select {
                case c.send <- m:
                default:
                    close(c.send)
                    delete(connections, c)
                    if len(connections) == 0 {
                        delete(r.Clients, m.Room)
                    }
                }
            }
```

```
for {
        msg := &Message{}
        err := c.conn.ReadJSON(&msg)
        // _, msg, err := c.conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            if websocket.IsUnexpectedCloseError(err, websocket.CloseGoingAway, websocket.CloseAbnormalClosure) {
                log.Printf("error: %v", err)
            }
            break
        }

        if msg.Type == 0 {
            newVideo := &NewVideo{}
            if err = json.Unmarshal(msg.Msg, &newVideo); err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            Roomb.Broadcast <- msg.Msg // ??? should i send the RawMessage
            online[msg.Room] = msg
        } else if msg.Type == 1 {
            if _, ok := online[msg.Room]; ok {
                online[msg.Room].Start = float64(time.Now().Unix() - online[msg.Room].Timestamp)
                c.send <- online[msg.Room]
            }
        } else if msg.Type == 2 {
            Roomb.Broadcast <- msg.Msg // ??? should i send the RawMessage
        }
        fmt.Println(msg)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove the "&" before `msg`. `msg` is already a pointer. This may make problems.
2. Your question is not very clear. If `msg.Type` defines what the `msg.Msg` is, then I recommend you make channels typed with the actual message type, parse the `msg.Msg`, then send it through the channel.

Comment: But there are 3 cases in which the message type struct changes. If I make the channel of type "Struct1" it won't be able to accept messages of "Struct2" or "Struct3".

Comment: I said make channels not "channel". Make as much channels as required. Listen to all of them using select statement

Comment: could you give us an example? I'm new using go so I don't know how to handle different request. For example, first request is to register to a group we need `{ cmd: "register", group: "games"}`, then we have connect request `{cmd: "connect-service", service:"updates"}` and finally a `{cmd: "update", data: { ... }}` how can I handle this situation?